# How to positon divs in a webpage using float?

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple webpage using HTML and CSS. However, when I resize my browser, the divs move around and lose their original positions. My only constraint is that I have to stick to float and not use table etc.

I want my layouts to look like this -

[image]

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <header>
        <div>
           <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>   
    </header>

    <div class="a"><b>One</b></div>
    <div class="b"><b>Two</b></div>
    <div class="c"><b>Three</b></div>
    <p>
    <div class="d"><b>Four</b></div>
<body>
```

CSS -

```
body {
  padding-top: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.a {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin-left: 20em;
}

.b {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

.c {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

.d {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 7em;
  line-height: 7em;
  margin-left: 65.25%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Why are you constrained to using `float`. It's how layouts were hacked a decade ago. This isn't what it was designed for. We have Grid and Flexbox now.

Comment: I feel like "losing their position" is the intended behaviour of `float`.

Comment: You are also not closing the `<html>`- and `<p>`-tag in your code. And it seems like you are using the [`class`es](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) like [`id`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). The way you use is not necessarily wrong, but using the attributes the intended way is generally easier to understand (except your are you using `.a`, `.b`, etc. more often than shown here, then you are doing it absolutely right).

Answer (score 0):

## Recommended: [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The parent needs the following properties:

- `display: flex`
- `flex-flow: row-reverse` to lay the children out in the order you want
- `flex-wrap: wrap` to allow them to wrap
- `justify-content: space-between` to space them evenly in the parent without gaps on either ends

Then you would need to specify for the children how many there would be in a row, and define their gaps using `margin` like this:
`min-width: calc(100% / AMOUNT_CHILDREN - HORIZONTAL_GAP * 2)` where `AMOUNT_CHILDREN` would be the amount of elements in a row, and `HORIZONTAL_GAP` would be the amount of the horizontal gap also defined in the `margin`-property.

**Note:**
The formula is only needed if you want the children to take up the specified space. If you want to let them expand or shrink when it seems fitting, you do not need to set it.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3 - 0.2rem * 2);
  background: gray; /* To show the size of the elements */
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
```

## [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

The parent needs the following properties:

- `display: grid`
- `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` for 3 columns with equal space
- Optional: `gap: X` where `X` is the amount of gap between your elements

The parent also needs the attribute `dir="rtl"` to lay out the children from right to left (CSS Grid doesn't currently support changing the wrap-direction, so we fall back to use the HTML-attribute `dir`).

The direction of the parent is inherited by its children, which might be unwanted. To revert this, you would have to add the attribute `dir="ltr"` to each child manually.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0.4rem;
}
div {
  background: gray; /* Only to show the size of the element */
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <div dir="ltr">A</div>
  <div dir="ltr">B</div>
  <div dir="ltr">C</div>
  <div dir="ltr">D</div>
</body>
```

**Note:**
HTML is a markup-language, and its main purpose is to convey meaning in the way it is formatted. To style the markup, CSS should be used.
Using HTML-features for styling that are not intended to be used in that way make the markup confusing, especially for people who rely on properly formatted HTML (e.g. blind people using screen-readers).
Always try to stick to CSS when it comes to styling. Of course, grouping-elements like `<div>`, `<span>`, etc. can and should still be used to support the styling, and might actually make semantically sense in the way you want to use them.

## Floating

First off, floating is actually intended to make surrounding elements be able to *float* around the floated element. This means, the way you want to use it is not what it is intended for. Hence I recommend the first approach (**Recommended: CSS Flexbox**), but for the sake of completeness, I will show how to do it using `float`.

Similar to the Flexbox-approach, we can give our children a calculated width (for the formula, see section **Recommended: CSS Flexbox**), and `float: right`.

```css
div {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3 - 0.2rem * 2);
  float: right;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
```

**Note:**
In my opinion, layout should be applied mostly from the parent.
Letting the element lay itself out would mean that for debugging you would have to check the CSS rules for *every single sibling* to find the cause of the problem.
Letting the parent lay out its children results in cleaner and perhaps less code, a more organized code-structure, and makes future changes easier to apply.

Obviously it isn't always possible to let the parent lay out its children. `position: absolute` or similar make the element have to lay out itself.

## P.S.

There are obviously many other ways to achieve the wanted behavior. However, some of them might be "hacky" in a way or not the modern approach. One could use `float: right` as was asked, or even use JS to place the children.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS flex or grid for the responsive webpages. Its the best practice to handle such problems.

Answer (score -1):

There's a million ways to organize your site like how you want. Here's one way. please take a look at this example I made for you.

```css
.container {
  text-align: right;
}

.a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 32%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.b {
display: inline-flex;
   width: 32%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.c {
display: inline-flex;
  width: 32%;
 background-color: gray;
}

.d {
display: inline-flex;
 width: 33%;
 background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <header>
        <div>
           <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>   
    </header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="a"><b>One</b></div>
    <div class="b"><b>Two</b></div>
    <div class="c"><b>Three</b></div>
    <div class="d"><b>Four</b></div>
</div>    
<body>
```